# Battery drain after dual booting windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 and Sleep problem in windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 13.10, windows-8, power-management

New to the forum here, had hoped for a better beginning to the open source world then this.

I had never installed Ubuntu before until a week back, followed all the precautions so that I didn't fall into trouble while dual booting windows 8.
I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 8.1 on a AsusN56VJ (intel i7 36300M,8gb ram, Nvidia 635M) on C drive itself,provided Ubuntu about 35 gb of free space to work with.
Everything worked fine and Ubuntu installed without a hitch.

I've been using Ubuntu for the past 1 week and I've got accustomed to it but I've been facing a few problems:

1) Battery drains very quickly. On windows 8.1, I used to get atleast 2-2.5 hours with decent load on. Even when I put the laptop to sleep(i.e by closing the lid or the fn+Zz hotkey) the battery drains too quickly for my liking

2) When using Windows, if I put my laptop to sleep for more than 5 minutes, if I try to wake the laptop on, it directly jumps to the default Grub screen . I'm not able to go to the previous session in windows, I need to restart windows all over again sacrificing all my previous work.

3)Once I shift from a session on windows to Ubuntu, all the apps that require information from my other drives(i.e D,E,F drives) seem to reset itself. I utilize EiskaltDC++, clementine, both these apps require access files from the other drives but I need to refresh/(remove+add again) for these apps to have access to these particular folders.

I understand this might be a problem due to the way I installed Ubuntu. Would it be better if I allocate a completely different drive for Ubuntu? I would be glad to do this, heck I would prefer to completely segregate windows 8 and Ubuntu  and that was the initial plan but most of the tutorials for dual booting never addressed this.

I like Ubuntu for the amount I've used it, if it were not for FIFA I would shift over to Ubuntu completely.

Your inputs/help would be well appreciated.

Edit:
1)As suggested by Sean, here are the outputs of etc/temp and mount -l
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07sfcCrfAN5TFE1RGkwRG5lRTQ/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07sfcCrfAN5YVllUlJULVYyUXc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How is Ubuntu installed? Is this a wubi situation (Ubuntu installed inside Windows like a Windows program) or did you make a partition for Ubuntu? Sounds like the former but unclear.

Comment: I freed up space on the C drive, made a bootable linux usb drive, went into a live session from the drive and then installed it from the drive, making a partition on the way.

Answer (score 0):

1) Battery life can be tweaked after you get the system running smoothly but likely poorer than Windows until an improvement happens in the kernel.

2) Check that your Windows session isn't going into hibernation after it's in sleep for a while. If you're seeing GRUB it probably hibernated. You should still be able to recover Windows if you select it in the GRUB menu. Disable hibernation and hybrid sleep in Windows to verify this is the case.

Add the output of these two commands to your question.

`less /etc/fstab`

`mount -l`

Comment: 2)1)Its not a problem with the power management settings:
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07sfcCrfAN5azlzTUpxc2s1OFU/edit?usp=sharing
Have edited the question with the two commands which you gave.

I'm not able to recover windows from the grub menu, if I select the Windows UEFI boot recovery setting, it shows that my windows has encountered a problem and needs to recover, I switch it of using the main power button and restart using Windows UEFI boot loader, it works properly.

Comment: Your links to Google Drive don not work for me.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/D4dDr Uploaded them here